# How to get users picture field displayed via _api/Web/Lists - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have created a field of type Person or Group with "show field  picture only".
When I look at the result I get back from the _api/web URL what I see is this as the field name:

```
<d:OData__x0061_wo9Id m:type="Edm.Int32">25</d:OData__x0061_wo9Id>
```

I need to get the right properties like username,accontname etc..out and I think need to build this url below:

```
/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname=name%40domain.com.au&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain-my.sharepoint.com%3A443%2FUser%2520Photos%2FProfile%2520Pictures%2Fusername_domain_com_au_MThumb.jpg
```

to be able to get each users picture.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your end goal? The link to the picture, or the user's profile info?

Answer (score 5):

For User field types you could specify `$expand` query option to return projected fields. In case of User fields the additional properties will be retrieved from `User Information List`.

Assume `Approver` is a single-valued User field. Then the following REST request will return `Approver` field properties such as `Id`,`Name`,`Title`:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=Approver/Id,Approver/Name,Approver/Title&$expand=Approver
```

### How to retrieve User Picture using SharePoint REST

Since `User Information List` contains `Picture` field, the following query demonstrates how to retrieve Picture for a specific user:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('User Information List')/items?$filter=Id eq <user id>&$select=Picture
```

where `<user id>` is the id of User

Note: The returned value is of `SP.FieldUrlValue` type:

```
{
   Url: '<url>',
   Description: '<description>'
}
```

### References

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the query Vadim.But i can i just get the link to the picture

Comment: The answer has been updated, see the section: How to retrieve User Picture using SharePoint REST

Comment: The problem with this is the User Information List can only be queried via REST if the currently logged in user has admin access to the site. Is there a way to get the photo URL of any user without the user needing admin access?

Comment: To have this work with different language packs, better use `/_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items?$filter=Id eq <user id>`, because the Title of this list varies between language packs. Also this should solve @Submits access troubles.